# Squeeze, sandwich or other words in English language?

Tags: terminology, definition

Mine is a simple question just of curiosity.

The most famous theorem of the comparison is the the *sandwich* or *squeeze rule* to calculate the limit of a sequence or function by comparing it with two other similar objects that "cling more and more" around the given one.

In Italy we call it "*il teorema dei due Carabinieri*".

Are there other names in English for this theorem?

Comment: It's also known as the [pinching theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you very very much. Can I ask to remove your comment and put an complete answer? So I'll show your answer(s) to my students directly on the question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), what is commonly called the squeeze or sandwich theorem is also called the pinching theorem.

Comment: "In many languages (e.g. French, German, Italian and Russian), the squeeze theorem is also known as the two policemen (and a drunk) theorem, or some variation thereof. The story is that if two policemen are escorting a drunk prisoner between them, and both officers go to a cell, then (regardless of the path taken, and the fact that the prisoner may be wobbling about between the policemen) the prisoner must also end up in the cell."

Comment: In French, we also have the *bottleneck principle* ( for french speaking readers, ‘principe du goulet’). The French wording of ‘two policemen theorem’ is ‘principe des gendarmes’

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde; I have not heard that in (American) English, but it is a colorful and understandable metaphor; same with the bottleneck principle, @Bernard